# How to access Vault credentials in pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, hashicorp-vault

We use the Vault plugin in our pipeline to read credentials from Vault. Now we also want to generate TLS certificates with Vault's PKI engine. For that I need the appRole secret id for Jenkins in my pipeline file. The secret is configured in Jenkins as 'Vault App Role Credential' and I don't know how to access it.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
withCredentials([VaultAppRoleCredential(credentialsId: 'vault_credentials'), roleIdVariable: 'roleId', secretIdVariable: 'secretId']) {
stage('generate certificate') {
    // authenticate with credentials against Vault
    // ...
}
```

}

My workaround at the moment is to duplicate the credentials and store the roleId and secretId additionally in a username+password credential in Jenkins.

Comment: That looks like it would work to me from what I know about Jenkins Pipeline and the Vault REST API. However, I would recommend transmitting the data as actual JSON and not a JSON string for ease of use.

Comment: The curl command does work with the correct credentials. What does not work is the withCredentials part. My workaround at the moment is to duplicate the credentials and store the roleId and secretId additionally in a username+password credential in Jenkins.

Edited question to make the point clearer.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/hashicorp-vault-plugin#usage-via-jenkinsfile?

Comment: Yes, but it only explains how to fetch secrets from Vault and how to configure the access to vault. My problem is that I want to access the credentials that are used to access vault which are stored in some Vault specific credentials type. The problem is more about the credentials binding plugin than about Vault. I think I would need some kind of VaultAppRole binding like AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding described here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Comment: Yeah, you might need an extension to the plugin's API for the functionality you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working example how to use Vault Credentials Token and use it to access vault secrets:

```
// Specify how to access secrets in Vault
def configuration = [
vaultUrl: 'https://hcvault.global.nibr.novartis.net',
vaultCredentialId: 'poc-vault-token',
engineVersion: 2
]

def secrets = [
[path: 'secret/projects/intd/common/accounts', engineVersion: 2, secretValues: 
    [
        [vaultKey: 'TEST_SYS_USER'],
        [vaultKey: 'TEST_SYS_PWD']
    ]
  ]
]

... [omitted pipeline]

stage ('Get Vault Secrets') {
  steps  {
    script {
      withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultTokenCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'poc-vault-token', vaultAddr: 'https://hcvault.global.nibr.novartis.net'], usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'artifactory-jenkins-user-password', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        withVault([configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {  
          sh """
            echo $env.VAULT_ADDR > hcvault-address.txt
            echo $env.VAULT_TOKEN > hcvault-token.txt
            echo $env.TEST_SYS_USER > sys-user-account.txt
          """.stripIndent()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```